# Format mac address using awk in a specific column

Tags: awk

I have a file with ip;mac address like this:

```
10.10.10.3;0:de:fb:42:6a:41  
10.10.10.4;00:de:fb:42:0:41
```

I need to perform an awk on second column so that the output would be a long format mac address:

```
10.10.10.3;00:de:fb:42:6a:41  
10.10.10.4;00:de:fb:42:00:41
```

I tried this:

```
 echo "10.10.10.3 00:de:fb:42:6a:41" | awk '{print $1";"$2}' | sed 's/\b\(\w\)\b/0\1/g'
```

But it screws up the first column also, result looks like this:

```
    10.10.10.03;00:de:fb:42:6a:41
```

instead of this:

```
    10.10.10.3;00:de:fb:42:6a:41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk. This adds a zero before each field of the MAC and only outputs the last two characters of a field.

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {$i="0" $i; $i=substr($i,length($i)-1,length($i))}; print $1 ";" $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' FS='[;:]' OFS=':' file
```

Output:

```
10.10.10.3;00:de:fb:42:6a:41
10.10.10.4;00:de:fb:42:00:41
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the length of a hex number is 1, we add the prefix "0", instead of the "%02d", because this will turn `a` into `00`, in fact the correct value would be `0a (DEC 10)`.

The following line will give the expected output. Explanations as inline comments:

```
awk -F';'             #separate by ";"
'{c=split($2,a,":")   # split the 2nd fields by ':'
printf "%s;",$1       # print the ip part ($1)
                      # for each hex, we check if a prefix "0" should be added
for(i=1;i<=c;i++)printf "%s%s",length(a[i])==1?"0"a[i]:a[i],i==c?"\n":":"
}' file
```

#### test:

```
kent$  awk -F';' '{c=split($2,a,":")
printf "%s;",$1
for(i=1;i<=c;i++)printf "%s%s",length(a[i])==1?"0"a[i]:a[i],i==c?"\n":":"}' file
10.10.10.3;00:de:fb:42:6a:41  
10.10.10.4;00:de:fb:42:00:41
```